# Formula for position of underline bar

Tags: font-design

I have to output some text onto an HTML5 canvas and need to provide an underline effect but cannot find the necessary metric for the underline position.

The canvas is quite primitive compared to other text manipulation environments in which I have worked, like GDI, and it does not provide the underline y-position AFAICS. The [textMetric](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/TextMetrics) seems to be the only facility to call for text measurements and it is not therein.

So - I am seeking a formula based approach on the assumption that such a think would reasonably exist in the world of font or graphics design.

I am hoping for something like 0.1 x font size below the baseline and 0.07 x fontsize high.

Would be grateful for any guidance or links etc.